# Finding data that has high similarity with current data?

Tags: android, algorithm, similarity

I have android app, and I want to find all data that have high similarities with selected data. example:

I have data that has value like this.

```
No Name           Distance  Rating  Price
1. Coffee Shop    1.3 KM    4.6     40
```

And I want to display all data that has similarities with the data above (assuming has weight to count like 'similarity score').
what kind algorithm that most suitable and easy to implement with my case?
From what i have been looking for i got several algorithm that i think it would works

```
- K-Means Clustering
- K-Nearest Neighbor
- ElasticSearch
- Cosine Similarity
```

In my current assumption, I still considering using K-Means because it's the only algorithm that I have learnt before

Answer (score 1):

If you use K-Means you will get groups of data clustered together. But here I think k-Nearest Neighbors would suit better for your query since from what I understand you will get queries of data and you are trying to find similar data to it. With k-Nearest Neighbors you can just adjust how many you want to include by saying, say nearest 5 or 50 neighbors. So I would go with kNN in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database like MySQL. SQL has joins and methods to sort similar data.